# What counts as an object vs a string in Typescript?

Tags: json, typescript, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions, json-path-expression

I am creating a Infrastructure-as-Code for a Step Functions Machine. One of these states is of type 'Task' which performs a DynamoUpdateItem on a DynamoDB table.

The code looks as following:

```
    const updateDDB = new tasks.DynamoUpdateItem(this, 'Update item into DynamoDB', {
      key: { ['Task'] : tasks.DynamoAttributeValue.fromString('Processing') },
      table: table,
      updateExpression: 'SET LastRun = :label',
      expressionAttributeValues: {
        ':label.$': DynamoAttributeValue.fromString(JsonPath.stringAt('$$.Execution.StartTime')), 
      },
      resultPath: JsonPath.DISCARD,
    });
```

However, I keep getting an error saying the schema validation failed, and that

"The value for the field ':label.$' must be a STRING that contains a JSONPath but was an OBJECT at /States/Update item into DynamoDB/Parameters'"

How the heck is it not a string?!

I have tried writing it as [':label.$'],
or even writing a .toString() function at the end of the JsonPath method

```
      expressionAttributeValues: {
        ':label.$': (DynamoAttributeValue.fromString(JsonPath.stringAt('$$.Execution.StartTime').toString())), 

      },
```

But nothing seems to work. I keep getting the same issue claiming that it's not a string.

Using something like JSON.stringify() doesn't work either because expressionAttributeValues takes a key and matches it with a DynamoAttributeValue.

Comment: I am not an expert on AWS, but the error does not say "must be a STRING". It says "must be a STRING that contains a JSONPath" which might suggest that you are indeed passing a string but it may not contain a JSONPath. But otherwise, it does claim you are passing an "OBJECT". But it could still be worth checking what the string says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**  Drop the `.$` suffix from `':label.$': DynamoAttributeValue(...)` in the expression attribute value definition.  The key should be simply `':label'`.

---

As @TobiasS says in the comments, the problem is with your State Machine task syntax.  The `.$` suffix on `:label.$` tells AWS to expect a JSONPath string [representing a path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html#input-output-parameters-keyvalue) to a value.   But a string is not valid State Machine syntax for this field.  A key-value pair is required.  The CDK docs have an [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.DynamoUpdateItem.html#example) with the correct syntax.

❌ What your CDK code synthesizes to:

```json
{
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
      ":label.$": { "S.$": "$$.Execution.StartTime" }
    },
}
```

✅ AWS expects the synthesized State Machine definition to be:

```json
{
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
      ":label": { "S.$": "$$.Execution.StartTime" }
    },
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain that. I tried what you proposed, and my CDK file did deploy. I am wondering however, will that perform the same action?

See, I am using a Step Function Definition file and re-writing it into CDK Typescript. 

The original definition file had the code as

`
          "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
            ":label.$": "$$.Execution.StartTime"
          }
`

but if I drop the .$, it results in a definition file that looks like this:

`
"ExpressionAttributeValues": {
  ":label": {
   "S.$": "$$.Execution.StartTime"
   }
},

Comment: @DevBob Glad to help.  Yes, the answer produces [valid UpdateItem syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-ExpressionAttributeValues).  It produces the expected result when the State Machine is executed, something like `"LastRun": "2023-01-27T18:20:33.910Z"`.